# Exercises for a person with limited mobility to lose weight

Tags: weight-loss, muscle-recovery

I'm recovering after hard doctor's error that attacked my legs mobility.

Legs returned theirs mobility, but they're weak.

1. Are there any exercises I can do lying on back or sitting to loose weight?
2. If you know any exercises to improve the legs muscles I'll be so appreciate.

Comment: What, more precisely, is the extent of the weakness in your legs I.e. can you stand easily, can you squat with no weight? Also what sort of equipment do you have access to?  Do you go to a gym? Do you have weights at home? or are you just looking for bodyweight exercises?

Comment: The first that comes to mind is swimming. This doesn't put much stress on the legs because you are 'weightless'.

Comment: What kind of physical therapy are you receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of extremely high volume endurance exercise, exercise energy expenditure is pretty low, and your body will generally compensate for it anyway by reducing non-exercise energy expenditure. Weight loss is going to be 100% diet, especially when you have mobility limitations that would preclude high volumes of exercise in the first place.

That said, the way to go with exercise is going to be to find an *entry point* to resistance exercise to start building back strength in your legs. Something like a step-up exercise, increasing the step height week-to-week (or as you are able to tolerate progressively higher steps) are a great entry point, since you can start them with a really low step, and raise the height as you build strength.

As for weight loss, your diet is really the only lever to pull here. Making sure you get lots of fiber, at least 30g+ per day, is going to set you up for success in managing hunger and satiety. Fresh, raw vegetables are like a cheat code when it comes to managing hunger. Avoid cooking them in butter or oil, as that makes the calories add up quickly.

Comment: Thanks for advices. The reason I got to the hospital where I was disabled is the.. diet) I ate shops mushrooms to get protein and not gain weight after knee injury and it have poisoned me. I lost about 50% of weight and almost lost my life. And then got ruined by doctors error. Irony.. Ok, I'll try to use diet

Answer (score 0):

Like Thomas said, the main thing to lose weight is diet. This is true for everyone actually (not just disabled). I recommend watching this video called "The Low fat Diet is Genocide": https://youtu.be/xyNHvogMFDI?si=9xGtFJOfGMBJO60O It's explains how the high fat diet will help you lose weight. I've heard a lot of weight loss success stories from people online on the Keto diet. Make sure you do as the video says about avoiding seed oils, they really are as dangerous as they say. And I recommend eating the highest quality food possible: organic produce, grass fed ruminant animals, pastured chickens, wild caught fish.
As for the exercises, I recommend looking up calisthenics, which means training using only your body weight. I got the book Monkey Strength by Kasey Stern: https://payhip.com/b/VyEG. It has a lot of exercises and a good plan to slowly work yourself up to harder exercises. Also, it's quite humourous. There's even a level 1 exercise you do on your back (it's hard for even me, with uninjured legs, to do)